# Using IIS URL Rewrite to redirect from one sub domain to another

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite, url, iis-8

I'm trying to set up IIS to redirect traffic from `https://sub.foo.com` to `https://www.foo.com`, but NOT redirecting any traffic to `https://sub.foo.com/bar`. The regular HTTP redirect module doesn't allow this kind of control (`https://sub.foo.com/bar` will be redirected) so I'm trying to use the URL Rewrite module, but despite much Googling, I can't find the right settings.

Currently my rule [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYNie.png) (I don't have the rep to embed images sadly) but isn't working. I've tried setting it at the server level and on both the "to" and "from" sites, but still no luck. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern to match only requests where the `path` part of the URI is empty:

```
^$
```

Put it into the "Match URL" field

Use a Condition to make sure it only applies to requests for the `sub.foo.com` domain by matching on the `{HTTP_HOST}` server variable. Pattern should be something like `^sub\.foo\.com$`